# eclipse Java EE IDE fails to start after updating

Tags: eclipse, java

During updating eclipse, my laptop rebooted suddenly, and after the reboot when i run eclipse it doesn't work.
I have tried many solutions such as editing the eclipse.ini file( i have define the "-vm" parameter as below( the image is content of the eclipse.ini):
[image]

so do have any solution to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curious why you posted an image rather than the actual text, which makes things a little bit more difficult - but I think you have a `_vm` (with an underscore) instead of a `-vm` (with a dash), which would cause issues.

If this doesn't fix it, you'll need to elaborate on "doesn't work".